# "What does it do?" or "what it does?", Which one is the correct/ best?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I have asked [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208967/set-timeout-in-angular-in-a-bit-complex-way) question on StackOverflow. In the last line, I have asked the following question.

"Could anyone please explain how this method of 'tick()' works and ***what does it do***? and Why?" According to this context which is the best way of asking this?
"What does it do?" or "what it does?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to say

> Could anyone please explain ... what does it do?

You should say

> Could anyone please explain ... what it does?

Here, "what it does" is not a question, it's a [Noun Clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/noun_clauses.htm).

"What it does?" is not a proper question on its own. We don't see, for example, subject-auxiliary verb inversion in it.